# YouTube to LBRY Video Uploader - V0.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, youtube

I have developed a Python script that allows users to upload videos from YouTube to LBRY. The script also performs video post-processing and database operations. I would like to request a code review to get feedback on the code quality and potential improvements. [[The Github Repo - v0.1.0]](https://github.com/walidmujahid/Vid2LBRY/tree/v0.1.0)

I have only used sqlite and have not yet tested with PostgreSQL or MySQL. My tests are not as comprehensive as I would like them to be, yet. I would like general feedback on how I could improve the code and any shortcomings of the current code. I especially would like feedback on the database design & database operations and how they could be better. I ultimately would like to use this as part of a webapp, maybe using flask, where users can put in a link to their videos and it will be uploaded to LBRY. Eventually I would like to have entire YouTube channels transfer and playlist transfers as features, and even support for other video platforms.

Directory Tree:

```
vid2lbry/
├── database
│   ├── database_operations.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── youtube_lbry.db
├── download_archive
├── downloader
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── youtube.py
├── pybry
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_config.ini
│   └── test_database_operations.py
├── uploader
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── lbry.py
├── app.log
├── config.ini
├── copy-config.ini
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── main.py
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

config.ini:

```ini
[Database]
dialect = sqlite

[sqlite]
db_path = database/youtube_lbry.db

[mysql]
host = localhost
port = 3306
user = your_mysql_user
password = your_mysql_password
name = youtube_lbry

[postgresql]
host = localhost
port = 5432
user = your_postgresql_user
password = your_postgresql_password
name = youtube_lbry

[LBRY]
channel_id = {Put your ID here}

[Downloader]
simulate = False
download_archive_dir = download_archive
download_archive = download_archive.txt
format = be
stvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio
outtmpl = download_archive/%%(id)s.%%(ext)s
postprocessors_key = FFmpegVideoConvertor
preferedformat = mp4
```

database/models.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Video(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'videos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_source = Column(String)
    video_id = Column(String, unique=True)
    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    video_url = Column(String)
    thumbnail_url = Column(String)
    downloads = relationship('Download', primaryjoin="Video.video_id==Download.video_id")
    uploads = relationship('LBRYUpload', primaryjoin="Video.video_id==LBRYUpload.video_id")

class Download(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'downloads'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_source = Column(String)
    video_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('videos.video_id'))
    download_path = Column(String)
    video = relationship(
        'Video',
        back_populates='downloads'
    )

class LBRYUpload(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lbryuploads'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_source = Column(String)
    video_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('videos.video_id'))
    lbry_status = Column(Integer)
    lbry_url = Column(String)
    video = relationship(
        'Video', 
        back_populates='uploads'
    )
```

database/database_operations.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from database.models import Base
from database.models import Video
from database.models import Download
from database.models import LBRYUpload


Session = sessionmaker()

def get_database_engine(config):
    """
    Get the database engine based on the configuration.

    Args:
        config (ConfigParser): The configuration object.

    Returns:
        sqlalchemy.engine.Engine: The SQLAlchemy database engine.
    """
    db_type = config.get('Database', 'dialect')
    if db_type == 'sqlite':
        db_path = config.get('sqlite', 'db_path')
        engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{db_path}', echo=True)
    elif db_type == 'mysql':
        # untested
        db_host = config.get('mysql', 'host')
        db_port = config.getint('mysql', 'port')
        db_user = config.get('mysql', 'user')
        db_password = config.get('mysql', 'password')
        db_name = config.get('mysql', 'name')
        engine = create_engine(f'mysql:///{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}', echo=True)
    elif db_type == 'postgresql':
        # untested
        db_host = config.get('postgresql', 'host')
        db_port = config.getint('postgresql', 'port')
        db_user = config.get('postgresql', 'user')
        db_password = config.get('postgresql', 'password')
        db_name = config.get('postgresql', 'name')
        engine = create_engine(f'postgresql:///{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}', echo=True)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid database type: {db_type}")

    return engine

def initialize_database(engine):
    """
    Create all database tables if they don't exist.

    Args:
        engine (sqlalchemy.engine.Engine): The SQLAlchemy database engine.
    """
    Session.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def create_video_record(
        session, 
        video_info: dict,
        video_url: str
    ):
    """
    Create a new Video record in the database.

    Args:
        session (sqlalchemy.orm.Session): The SQLAlchemy database session.
        video_info (dict): The video information dictionary.
        youtube_url (str): The URL of the YouTube video.
    """
    try:
        video = Video(
            video_source=video_info['video_source'],
            video_id=video_info['id'],
            title=video_info['title'],
            description=video_info['description'],
            video_url=video_url,
            thumbnail_url=video_info['thumbnail']
        )
        session.merge(video)
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e

def create_download_record(session, video_info: dict):
    """
    Create a new Download record in the database.

    Args:
        session (sqlalchemy.orm.Session): The SQLAlchemy database session.
        video_info (dict): The video information dictionary.
    """
    try:
        download = Download(
            video_source=video_info['video_source'],
            video_id=video_info['id'], 
            download_path=video_info['download_path']
        )
        session.add(download)
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e

def create_lbry_upload_record(session, video_info: dict):
    """
    Create a new LBRYUpload record in the database.

    Args:
        session (sqlalchemy.orm.Session): The SQLAlchemy database session.
        video_info (dict): The video information dictionary.
    """
    try:
        lbry_upload = LBRYUpload(
            video_source=video_info['video_source'],
            video_id=video_info['id'],
            lbry_status=0, 
            lbry_url=None
        )
        session.add(lbry_upload)
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e

def update_lbry_upload_record(
        session, 
        video_id: str,
        lbry_url: str, 
        lbry_status: int
    ):
    """
    Update the LBRYUpload record in the database.

    Args:
        session (sqlalchemy.orm.Session): The SQLAlchemy database session.
        video_id (str): The ID of the video.
        lbry_url (str): The LBRY URL of the uploaded video.
        lbry_status (int): The status of the LBRY upload (-1: Failed, 0: Pending, 1: Success).
    """
    try:
        lbry_upload = session.query(LBRYUpload).filter(LBRYUpload.video_id == video_id).one()
        lbry_upload.lbry_url = lbry_url
        lbry_upload.lbry_status = lbry_status
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e
```

downloader/youtube.py:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
import re
import subprocess

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL


class YouTubeProcessor:
    def __init__(self, download_archive, youtube_url, ydl_opts):
        """
        Initialize the YouTubeProcessor.

        Args:
            download_archive (str): Path to the download archive directory.
            youtube_url (str): The URL of the YouTube video to process.
            ydl_opts (dict): Options for youtube-dl.
        """
        self.download_archive = download_archive
        self.video_source = 'youtube'
        self.youtube_url = youtube_url
        self.ydl_opts = ydl_opts

    def is_valid_youtube_url(self):
        """
        Check if the provided URL is a valid YouTube URL.

        Returns:
            bool: True if the URL is valid, False otherwise.
        """
        pattern = r'^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$'
        return bool(re.match(pattern, self.youtube_url))

    def process_video(self):
        """
        Process the YouTube video by downloading and post-processing.

        Returns:
            dict: The video information dictionary.
        """
        if not self.is_valid_youtube_url():
            raise ValueError("Invalid YouTube URL: Please provide a valid YouTube URL.")

        with YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
            video_info = ydl.extract_info(
                    self.youtube_url, download=True
        )

        video_info['video_source'] = self.video_source

        # Check if the downloaded file is already in MP4 format
        mp4_filename = os.path.join(
                self.download_archive, 
                f"{video_info['id']}.mp4"
        )

        if os.path.exists(mp4_filename):
            # Set the downloaded file path to the MP4 file directly
            video_info['download_path'] = mp4_filename

        else:
            # Perform post-processing using ffmpeg to convert to MP4 format
            original_filename = os.path.join(
                    self.download_archive, 
                    f"{video_info['id']}.{video_info['ext']}"
            )
            mp4_filename = os.path.join(
                    self.download_archive, 
                    f"{video_info['id']}.mp4"
            )
            subprocess.run(
                    [
                        'ffmpeg', 
                        '-i', 
                        original_filename, 
                        '-c', 
                        'copy', 
                        mp4_filename
                    ], 

                    check=True
            )

            # Set the downloaded file path to the MP4 file
            video_info['download_path'] = mp4_filename

        return video_info
```

uploader/lbry.py:

```py
from pybry import LbrydApi

class LBRYUploader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lbry = LbrydApi()

    def upload(self, video_info):
        """
        Upload the video to LBRY.

        Args:
            video_info (dict): The video information dictionary.

        Returns:
            str: The LBRY URL of the uploaded video, or None if the upload failed.
        """
        try:
            lbry_results = self.lbry.publish(
                name=video_info['id'], preview=False, blocking=True, bid='0.001',
                file_path=video_info['download_path'],
                channel_id="68dad212fddb3d6cb294278e11a303a6a98f2905",
                thumbnail_url=video_info['thumbnail'],
                title=video_info['title'], description=video_info['description']
            )
            return lbry_results[0]['outputs'][0]['permanent_url']
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error uploading video to LBRY: {e}")
            if hasattr(e, 'response'):
                print(f"LBRY API Response: {e.response}")
            return None
```

main.py:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
import logging
import configparser
import argparse

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from database.database_operations import get_database_engine
from database.database_operations import initialize_database
from database.database_operations import create_video_record
from database.database_operations import create_download_record
from database.database_operations import create_lbry_upload_record
from database.database_operations import update_lbry_upload_record
from downloader.youtube import YouTubeProcessor
from uploader.lbry import LBRYUploader


# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
        filename='app.log', 
        level=logging.ERROR, 
        format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process a YouTube video and upload it to LBRY.')
    parser.add_argument('youtube_url', type=str, help='URL of the YouTube video to process and upload to LBRY.')
    return parser.parse_args()

def read_config(config_file):
    """
    Read and parse the configuration file.

    Args:
        config_file (str): Path to the configuration file.

    Returns:
        configparser.ConfigParser: The parsed configuration object.
    """
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_file)

    return config

def main():
    # Read the configuration file
    config = read_config('config.ini')
    download_archive = config.get('Downloader', 'download_archive')
    download_archive_dir = os.path.abspath(
            config.get('Downloader', 'download_archive_dir')
    )

    # Read settings from the configuration file
    channel_id = config.get('LBRY', 'channel_id')
    ydl_opts = {
        'simulate': config.getboolean('Downloader', 'simulate'),
        'download_archive': os.path.join(download_archive_dir, download_archive),
        'format': config.get('Downloader', 'format'),
        'outtmpl': config.get('Downloader', 'outtmpl'),

    }

    args = parse_arguments()
    url = args.youtube_url

    try:
        # Video processing
        youtube_processor = YouTubeProcessor(download_archive_dir, url, ydl_opts)
        video_info = youtube_processor.process_video()

        # Database operations
        engine = get_database_engine(config)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

        with Session() as session:
            # Create tables if they don't exist
            initialize_database(engine)

            # Perform database operations within a transaction block
            session.begin()

            create_video_record(session, video_info, url)
            create_download_record(session, video_info)
            create_lbry_upload_record(session, video_info)

            session.commit()

            # LBRY upload
            lbry_uploader = LBRYUploader()
            lbry_url = lbry_uploader.upload(video_info)

            # Update LBRYUpload record with the LBRY URL and status
            if lbry_url:
                print(f"LBRY URL: {lbry_url}")

                # Set status to success
                update_lbry_upload_record(
                        session, 
                        video_info['id'], 
                        lbry_url, 
                        lbry_status=1
                )

                session.commit()
            else:
                print("LBRY upload failed.")

                # Set status to failed
                update_lbry_upload_record(
                        session, 
                        video_info['id'], 
                        lbry_url=None, 
                        lbry_status=-1
                )

                session.commit()
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        print(f"An unexpected error occured: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So far, I only have tests for the database operations functions.

tests/conftests.py:

```py
import pytest
from configparser import ConfigParser


def load_test_config():
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read("tests/test_config.ini")
    return config

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    config = load_test_config()
    db_choices = list(config.sections())[1:]
    db_choices_str = ", ".join(db_choices)
    parser.addoption(
        "--db-type",
        action="store",
        default="sqlite",
        choices=db_choices,
        help=f"Specify the database type to use for testing. Available choices: {db_choices_str} (default: sqlite).",
    )
```

tests/test_database_operations.py:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pytest
import os
import sys

# Get the parent directory of the current directory (vid2lbry directory)
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Add the parent directory to the Python module search path
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from database.models import Base
from database.models import Video
from database.models import Download
from database.models import LBRYUpload
from database.database_operations import get_database_engine
from database.database_operations import initialize_database
from database.database_operations import create_video_record
from database.database_operations import create_download_record
from database.database_operations import create_lbry_upload_record
from database.database_operations import update_lbry_upload_record


def load_test_config():
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read("tests/test_config.ini")
    return config

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session(request):
    db_type = request.config.getoption("--db-type")

    # Load the test configuration from the config file
    config = load_test_config()    

    engine = get_database_engine(config)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Initialize the database with tables
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    return session


# Test cases for database operations

def test_create_video_record(db_session):
    # Test creating a video record in the database

    # Sample video information
    video_info = {
        'video_source': 'youtube',
        'id': 'PXTsVwd_j5A',
        'title': 'THE JAMIL AL-AMIN CONSPIRACY',
        'description': 'The Jamil Al-Amin (H. Rap Brown) Conspiracy. A true leader who walked with Martin Luther King, propagated the ideas of Malcolm X and became the Minister of Defense of the Black Panther Party is still alive and jailed under suspicious circumstances. Free Jamil Al Amin!',
        'thumbnail': 'https://example.com/sample_thumbnail.jpg',
    }

    # Perform the operation
    create_video_record(db_session, video_info, 'https://youtu.be/PXTsVwd_j5A')

    # Check if the video record is created
    video = db_session.query(Video).filter(Video.video_id == 'PXTsVwd_j5A').first()
    assert video is not None
    assert video.video_source == 'youtube'
    assert video.title == 'THE JAMIL AL-AMIN CONSPIRACY'
    assert video.description == 'The Jamil Al-Amin (H. Rap Brown) Conspiracy. A true leader who walked with Martin Luther King, propagated the ideas of Malcolm X and became the Minister of Defense of the Black Panther Party is still alive and jailed under suspicious circumstances. Free Jamil Al Amin!'
    assert video.video_url == 'https://youtu.be/PXTsVwd_j5A'
    assert video.thumbnail_url == 'https://example.com/sample_thumbnail.jpg'

def test_create_download_record(db_session):
    # Test creating a download record in the database

    # Sample video information
    video_info = {
        'video_source': 'youtube',
        'id': 'PXTsVwd_j5A',
        'download_path': 'download_archive/PXTsVwd_j5A.mp4',
    }

    # Perform the operation
    create_download_record(db_session, video_info)

    # Check if the download record is created
    download = db_session.query(Download).filter(Download.video_id == 'PXTsVwd_j5A').first()
    assert download is not None
    assert download.video_source == 'youtube'
    assert download.video_id == 'PXTsVwd_j5A'
    assert download.download_path == 'download_archive/PXTsVwd_j5A.mp4'

def test_create_lbry_upload_record(db_session):
    # Test creating an LBRYUpload record in the database

    # Sample video information
    video_info = {
        'video_source': 'youtube',
        'id': 'PXTsVwd_j5A',
    }

    # Perform the operation
    create_lbry_upload_record(db_session, video_info)

    # Check if the LBRYUpload record is created
    lbry_upload = db_session.query(LBRYUpload).filter(LBRYUpload.video_id == 'PXTsVwd_j5A').first()
    assert lbry_upload is not None
    assert lbry_upload.video_source == 'youtube'
    assert lbry_upload.video_id == 'PXTsVwd_j5A'
    assert lbry_upload.lbry_status == 0
    assert lbry_upload.lbry_url is None
```